# clear text-field after submit in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, crud

can anyone help how to clear the text field after sending the message? I tried many approaches but it didn't work. I tried to use preventDefualt and setFirstname('') empty string but it didn't work also. thanks for helping , as I need to solve this issue

```
const [firstename, setFirstName] = useState('');
  const [lastename, setLastName] = useState('');
const sendCollectionRef = collection(db, 'messages');
  const [loader, setLoader] = useState(false);
  const creatSend = async () => {
    setLoader(true);

    await addDoc(sendCollectionRef, {
      Firstname: firstename,
      Lastname: lastename,
      Email: email,
      Message: message,
    })
      .then(() => {
        setLoader(false);
        setLastName('');

        alert('Your Message has been sent');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error.message);
        setLoader(false);
      });
  };
<TextField
                      id="outlined-basic"
                      label="Message"
                      multiline
                      rows={4}
                      variant="outlined"
                      placeholder="Type Your Message"
                      fullWidth
                      style={{ backgroundColor: '#2b2b2b' }}
                      onChange={(event) => {
                        setMessage(event.target.value);
                      }}
                    />
                    <Grid xs={12} item class="send-spacer">
                      <LoadingButton
                        onClick={creatSend}
                        endIcon={<SendIcon />}
                        variant="contained"
                        style={{
                          background: loader ? '#ccc' : ' rgb(2, 2, 110)',
                        }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, if you're not using a library to handle forms(e.g. formik), you have to bind each textfield value to a local state.

```
const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');

<TextField name="firstName" value={firstName} onChange={e => setFirstName(e.target.value) ...... />
<TextField name="lastName" value={lastName} onChange={e => setLastName(e.target.value) ...... />
```

Then in the submit handler, once you have sent your data to the server, you can reset the field values just changing the states:

```
setLastName('');
setFirstName('');
```

Answer (score 0):

const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');

<TextField name="firstName" value={firstName} onChange={e => setFirstName(e.target.value) ...... />
<TextField name="lastName" value={lastName} onChange={e => setLastName(e.target.value) ...... />
Then in the submit handler, once you have sent your data to the server, you can reset the field values just changing the states:

setLastName({firstName: " "});
setFirstName({lastName: " "});

You can use useRef() also to clear the values.

Comment: You should format your answer to make it more readable and understandable